# Data is not displayed in chartjs when using parsing: false;

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to display the graph using parsing: false, but the data is not displayed at all. The [site](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/performance.html#parsing) says that this is an internal format that will work if you disable parsing.

```
 {
        type: 'line',
        options: {
            parsing: false,
            animation: false,
            pointRadius: 0,
            normalized: true,
            spanGaps: false,
            scales: {
                x: {
                    ticks: {
                        source: 'auto',
                        // Disabled rotation for performance
                        // maxRotation: 0
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        data: {
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: [
                        {x: 1, y: 2},
                        {x: 2, y: 2},
                        {x: 3, y: 6},
                        {x: 4, y: 2},
                        {x: 5, y: 3},
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
    }
```

Using:

```
"chart.js": "^4.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the internal format of a line chart the x value is a category scale so your x values need to be strings instead of numbers or you need to change it to a linear scale by setting: `options.scales.y.type` to `'linear'`